# Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java when i run gradle command in terminal

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, gradle, gradlew

I am working in Ubuntu 16.04. I need to install gradle and the gradle is installed when i checked with sudo apt list --installed command but when i use gradle -version command it shows the following error,
JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

In sudo vim /etc/environment file,

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"
http_proxy="http://username:password@IP:port no/"
https_proxy="https://IP:port no/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://IP:port no/"
```

I don't know where i made mistakes. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: try setting the path till bin directory only, no further  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/`

Answer (score 12):

On a 64bit openSuse 64 42.1 box;

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

provided;

```
/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin/java
```

But;

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
```

is the path that worked and allowed java emulator to run.

So i think we have to manually browse our file system and see what path to choose.

Comment: Working on Debian

Answer (score 2):

Today I faced this problem. I am using the default java that comes with your linux distro (so in my case, linux mint).

```
$ whereis java
```

This command gave me

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java
```

So, I opened `/user/bin`. There was a link to `Java`. I right clicked it and selected `follow original link`. This lead me to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`.
So now that I know where this java is, I opened my `.bashrc` file, and edited the JAVA_HOME.
So for my case,

```
## My Custom variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This solved the problem.

Now if you are using some other java (say you downloaded from oracle and extracted the zip file ...), then you have to add that location. So for example, if your java is in `/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current`, then

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I was installing hadoop using https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html I completed all the steps until editing the JAVA_HOME variable in hadoop-env.sh file. to locate the actual path of the java I followed the same procedure as you did, but while executing ./hadoop command I am getting error that ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I see a mismatch. In your enviornment file the JAVA_HOME is set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/" and your mentioned that the error that you got relates to the JAVA_HOME as "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"

If you JAVA is really installed in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle directory, then you need to ensure that the JAVA_HOME is set to that directory. And also your PATH reflects $JAVA_HOME/bin in it.

I typically install Oracle JDK/JRE separately in a separate directory such as /usr/local/jdk1.8.0 etc.

Comment: now i have setted the PATH as you said as java -8- oracle but still getting same error as invalid directory "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"

Comment: On your command path you should see the same JAVA_HOME and PATH. For that you can run "echo $JAVA_HOME" and "echo $PATH" on the command prompt.

Comment: i used "echo$JAVA_HOME" and i can see  the path as /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

Comment: That is wrong. Your JAVA_HOME should be only till /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: i setted upto /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle in env file but it shows /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java in terminal. what should i do please help me.

Comment: Please try to relogin to the machine and check the JAVA_HOME is set correctly or not. Or else set it manually for now and try to execute your command.

Comment: Now, when I run sudo gradle command in my source path it will run and after this giving sudo ./gradlew assemble will give the following line as,      Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle3.1.bin.zip                            After this, it throws exception error.

Comment: I guess your original question is resolved now. This looks like some other issue.

Comment: Yes that was resolved. Now when i run ./gradlew assemble command it is trying to download something like this,

Comment: Now when i run sudo ./gradlew assemble command in source path it trying to download something like this,                                             Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Exception in thread "main" java.net.Connect Exception: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Comment: Is the machine connected and able to ping/connect to the gradle server?

Answer (score 0):

check the jvm installtion folder from Files 
eg : /usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle

then in terminal run sudo nano /etc/environment and add the line
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle"

Then open terminal and run 
`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle"`